# How to read PNG image to NSImage

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

how can i read PNG image to NSImage. I tried the following way,but when i get the width and size of the image i'm getting some weird value.. if any one can direct me in right path.. highly appropriate..

```
 NSImage * picture =  [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [bundleRoot stringByAppendingString:tString]];

 NSLog(@"sixe %d %d",picture.size.width, picture.size.height);
 if( picture ){ 
  NSLog(@"Picture is not null"); 
 }else {
  NSLog(@"Picture is null.");
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: This seems to disregard the alpha channel in my .png. Is there a way to retain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code to load the image is correct.

The code to display the size is incorrect; NSSize's members are CGFloat which should be print with the %f format string:

```
NSLog(@"size %f %f",picture.size.width, picture.size.height);
```

Comment: Thx for quick reply, can you tell me how to convert the below code to Mac OS X

Iphone App-->using UIKit
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(offset.x * scale, offset.y * scale, scale * size.width, scale * size.height);

UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
[image drawInRect:rect];
UIGraphicsPopContext();

Comment: Take a look at the Drawing Guide (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/GraphicsContexts/GraphicsContexts.html). It explains how to get a graphical context and how to draw images.

Answer (score 2):

Use `[NSImage imageNamed:tString]`. tString should be the base file name of the image file; and need not contain a file extension.

Comment: Thx for quick reply, can you tell me how to convert the below code to Mac OS X

Iphone App-->using UIKit
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(offset.x * scale, offset.y * scale, scale * size.width, scale * size.height);

UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
[image drawInRect:rect];
UIGraphicsPopContext();