# Copy an image to MacOS clipboard using python

Tags: python, image, clipboard

I want to copy an image (PIL image) to clipboard on Mac OS
I tried dozens of different ways to do that. Most of python clipboard modules like pyclip or clipboard doesn't support images.

I found a code that does that on windows, but nothing for mac. I tried to use QT, installed it through brew, for some reason brew installed a new python 3.7.2 (I had 3.7.1) and messed up with terminal commands like python and python3. I managed to fix it, but it's very frustrating. And I couldn't get it to work anyway.

I've seen a method with win32 clipboard, but it's for windows only. I tried various different modules, but none of them accept images. I couldn't come up with a solution, so I'm here asking for help.

A little background. I'm writing an app that will save the image from the clipboard and saves it to a file. I have no problem with this, but I also want to store what I saved and later to be able to pull it back to the clipboard. Like Open Last Saved.

Comment: The built-in python in MacOS has a set of interface libraries to the OS frameworks. Try the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692010/cant-access-nspasteboard-using-pyobjc

Answer (score 5):

This little piece of ugliness works and loads `"image.jpg"` onto the clipboard...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file "image.jpg") as JPEG picture)'])
```

Comment: It didn't really work. It copied thumbnail of a png image for some reason. I just pasted it to imgur: https://i.imgur.com/Jy7xPO2.png

Comment: Please check again - it works fine on my machine with any size image. You can check an image's size with `sips` in Terminal like this `sips -g all someImage.jpg`

Comment: I got it to work with JPEG image, but with PNG it only uploads the thumbnail

Comment: When I try to copy PNG, it doesn't work:
subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file "/Users/irondsd/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot 2019-01-02 17.38.55.7.png") as PNG picture)'])
122:129: syntax error: Expected “,” but found class name. (-2741)
CompletedProcess(args=['osascript', '-e', 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file "/Users/irondsd/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot 2019-01-02 17.38.55.7.png") as PNG picture)'], returncode=1)

Comment: Oh! That is odd. It works with `JPEG`, `TIFF` and `GIF` just fine. Maybe StackOverflow's top Applescripter (@vadian) will know...

Answer (score 1):

found this solution from https://github.com/RhetTbull/textinator/blob/main/src/pasteboard.py, copying from a .png or .tiff file, similar to the osascript solution but this hooks directly into pyObjC.

```
from Foundation import NSData
from AppKit import NSPasteboardTypePNG, NSPasteboardTypeTIFF, NSPasteboard

format = "PNG" # (or "TIFF")
filename = "/path/to/image.png"  # set this to filepath where img is saved
pasteboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()

image_data = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile_(filename)
if format not in ("PNG", "TIFF"):
  raise TypeError("Invalid format, must be PNG or TIFF")
format_type = NSPasteboardTypePNG if format == "PNG" else NSPasteboardTypeTIFF
pasteboard.clearContents()
pasteboard.setData_forType_(image_data, format_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Marks answer doesnt work for me for pngs.

But i found this which works perfectly:
http://web.archive.org/web/20221029163614/http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=3816

create a `impbcopy.m` with

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <unistd.h>
BOOL copy_to_clipboard(NSString *path)
{
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681630/how-to-read-png-image-to-nsimage
  NSImage * image;
  if([path isEqualToString:@"-"])
  {
    // http://caiustheory.com/read-standard-input-using-objective-c 
    NSFileHandle *input = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
    image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[input readDataToEndOfFile]];
  }else
  { 
    image =  [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
  }
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/18124824/148668
  BOOL copied = false;
  if (image != nil)
  {
    NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pasteboard clearContents];
    NSArray *copiedObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObject:image];
    copied = [pasteboard writeObjects:copiedObjects];
    [pasteboard release];
  }
  [image release];
  return copied;
}

int main(int argc, char * const argv[])
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  if(argc<2)
  {
    printf("Usage:\n\n"
      "Copy file to clipboard:\n    ./impbcopy path/to/file\n\n"
      "Copy stdin to clipboard:\n    cat /path/to/file | ./impbcopy -");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  NSString *path= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
  BOOL success = copy_to_clipboard(path);
  [pool release];
  return (success?EXIT_SUCCESS:EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Compile `gcc -Wall -g -O3 -ObjC -framework Foundation -framework AppKit -o impbcopy impbcopy.m`

and run `./impbcopy path/to/file.png`

---

you can now use this from within python:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run("impbcopy", "/path/to/file.png")
```

when added to your path, or alternatively specifying the path directly

Comment: this answer is not relevant to a python question