# Need a way to load image file into Mac clipboard using Python

Tags: python, image, macos, clipboard

I have a Python program that I'm porting to Mac.  I need to load a saved image file into the clipboard so that it can be pasted into a document using cmd + v.

[This was the closest thread to what I need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008175/copy-an-image-to-macos-clipboard-using-python) but the solutions don't work because my osascript filepath is unknown.  It is a variable defined in Python by the user and I'm struggling with syntax necessary to pass the variable from Python to osascript.

This doesn't work:

```
import subprocess


def imagepath():                               
    f=open('config.txt')
    line=f.readlines()
    inpath = (line[2])    
    print(inpath)
    return(inpath)

imagepath()

subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file  "+ str(inpath) + /tc.jpg") as JPEG picture)'])
```

inpath prints as: /Users/admin/Desktop/PROGRAMMING which is the correct path but it results in "execution error: Can’t make file ":+ str(inpath) + :tc.jpg" into type file. (-1700)"

Nor does this:

```
import subprocess


def imagepath():                               
    f=open('config.txt')
    line=f.readlines()
    inpath = (line[2])    
    print(inpath)
    return(inpath)

imagepath()

subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file  """+ str(inpath) + /tc.jpg""") as JPEG picture)'])
```

It results in: "syntax error: Expected “,” but found “"”. (-2741)"

The following:

```
import subprocess


def imagepath():                                 # check line 1 of config file (screencap name)
    f=open('config.txt')
    line=f.readlines()
    inpath = (line[2])    # note: confusing.  0=line 1, 1=line2 etc.
    print(inpath)
    return(inpath)

imagepath()

subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file  ''' + str(inpath) + '''/tc.jpg") as JPEG picture)'])
```

Results in: "SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  Updated code below:

```
def imagepath():                                 # check line 1 of config file (screencap name)
    f=open('config.txt')
    line=f.readlines()
    inpath = line[2].strip('\n')
    print(inpath)
    return(inpath)

imagepath()

subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", "set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file \"" + inpath  + "/tc.jpg\") as JPEG picture)" ])
```

Now returns: "NameError: name 'inpath' is not defined"

EDIT 2: Completes without error but fails to load to clipboard.

```
import subprocess


def imagepath():                                 # check line 1 of config file (screencap name)
    f=open('config.txt')
    line=f.readlines()
    inpath = (line[2]).strip('\n')
    print(inpath)
    return(inpath)
    subprocess.run(
        ["osascript", "-e", "set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file \"" + inpath + "/tc.jpg\") as JPEG picture)"])
imagepath()
```

This returns no errors and prints correct path but does not add the file to the clipboard.

Comment: You need to pick up the returned value, `inpath = imagepath()`

Comment: You have added the subprocess call **after** the function returns! It will not run there. Delete the `return(inpath)` part.

Comment: Working now.  Rookie mistake, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have likely got a linefeed at the end of your string `inpath`, so try:

```
inpath = line[2].strip('\n')
```

Then you want:

```
subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", "set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file \"" + inpath  + "/tc.jpg\") as JPEG picture)" ])
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried this with no result.  Is the following correct syntax? subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file  " + str(inpath) + /tc.jpg") as JPEG picture)'])

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the `subprocess` part too. Please have another look.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping.  I have copied/pasted your code exactly and I now get "NameError: name 'inpath' is not defined".  Full code has been appended to the original question above in case I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: I tried running the subprocess within the function imagepath() and then executing imagepath().  It prints the correct path, and it finishes with no errors, but it does not copy the image to the clipboard.

Comment: @MattW Please click `edit` under your code and make your question show the **actual** code you run and the errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mac has a command line utility for this:

pbcopy

ONLY reads std in.  E.g.

cat image.jpg | pbcopy